# Insert into database fails

Tags: python, sqlite

My code:

```
@app.route('/projects/create', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def add():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.form["id"]
        name = request.form["name"]
        text = request.form["s_text"]

        try:
            projects.db.executemany("INSERT INTO projects  (?,?,?)", [id], [name], [text])
            projects.db.commit()
            return redirect("/projects")
        except:
            return "Error 404"
    else:
        return render_template("create.html")
```

I'm trying to insert into database but nothing worked.

Comment: What have you tried? And what errors did you face then?

Comment: i tried to delete the try statement. This is the error i get all the time:    File "main.py", line 43, in add
    projects.db.executemany("INSERT INTO projects  (?,?,?)", [id], [name], [text])
TypeError: executemany expected 2 arguments, got 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have many rows, you have one.  You need to use the VALUES keyword to signal that values are coming.  And your three fields need to be ONE list.  You need

```
projects.db.execute("INSERT INTO projects VALUES (?,?,?)", [id, name, text] )
```